# Draw multiple rectangles with delays between them

Tags: java, android, canvas, handler, ondraw

I am using `Handler` post delay to call `onDraw` each time I want to draw new rectangle, but for every new rectangle erase the previous one ..
How can I make the canvas keep the content of all rectangles: 
My code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import com.adhamenaya.microchart.model.ChartData;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 18/12/2016.
 */

public class ColumnChart extends Chart implements Runnable {

    private int mSpace = 0;
    private int mColumnSize = 0;
    private int mColumnsCount = 0;
    private int mCurrentStart = 0;
    private float mHeightUnit = 0;
    private int mHeightDiff;
    int columnIndex = 0;

    private Handler mHandler;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Iterator mDataIterator;

    static final long FRAME_TIME = 100;
    private ArrayList<Rect> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rect>();


    public ColumnChart(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mHandler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void prepare() {
        if (mChartData != null && mChartData.getSingleData().size() > 0) {
            mColumnsCount = mChartData.getSingleData().size();

            // Column size, 1 is added to reserve a space at the end of the chart
            mColumnSize = (int) ((mWidth / (mColumnsCount)) * 0.9);

            // Calculate the space between the bars
            mSpace = (mWidth / mColumnsCount) - mColumnSize;

            // Calculate height unit
            // Calculate 80% of the total height
            float height08 = mHeight * 0.8f;
            mHeightUnit = height08 / mChartData.getMax();

            // Draw bars
            mDataIterator = mChartData.getSingleData().entrySet().iterator();

            mMainPaint = getRectPaint();


            // Create rect objects
            while (mDataIterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) mDataIterator.next();

                int columnHeight = (int) ((int) entry.getValue() * mHeightUnit);
                String key = (String) entry.getKey();

                // Shift the
                mCurrentStart += mSpace;

                // Calculate the difference between the total height and the height of the column
                mHeightDiff = mHeight - columnHeight;

                mCurrentStart += mColumnSize;

                mDataIterator.remove();

                Rect rect = new Rect(mCurrentStart, mHeightDiff,
                        mCurrentStart + mColumnSize, mHeight);
                rectangles.add(rect);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintChart(Canvas canvas) {

    }

    @Override
    public void setData(ChartData data) {
        this.mChartData = data;
        prepare();
        mHandler.post(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        // Get measured height and width of the view
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasurement(widthMeasureSpec, mWidth),
                getMeasurement(heightMeasureSpec, mHeight));

        // mWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        // mHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if(columnIndex > 0 && columnIndex<rectangles.size())
            canvas.drawRect(rectangles.get(columnIndex), getRectPaint());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if(columnIndex<rectangles.size()){
            invalidate();
            columnIndex++;
            mHandler.postDelayed(this,FRAME_TIME);
        }else{
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you keeping the rects for drawing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a FrameLayout on which you want to draw rectangles. Create a view every time you are drawing a new circle. Draw circle on newly created view and the add that view to FrameLayout. Background of the view will be transparent by default. If not then set the background as transparent. This way your previous rectangles will be visible and new rectangle will be drawn on existing rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

Your are near to make it done! Just call you prepare after calling `invalidate` method.

```
 @Override
public void run() {

    if(columnIndex<rectangles.size()){
        invalidate();
        columnIndex++;
        mHandler.postDelayed(this,FRAME_TIME);
    }else{
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
        eraseAll();
    }
}
```

...

```
 public void eraseAll() {
    this.canvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    invalidate();
    prepare();
}
```

Comment: where to call eraseAll ?

Comment: I can not get the point of this function eraseAll ? I want to keep all already drawn rectangles ..

Comment: So create a separated customeview one for you rectangles, and another for your Chart View. 
Or you can keep rectangles views point, and change the positions, then in your thread draw the new one. This guaranty the previous one would be erases.

Comment: @AdhamEnaya every time you are drawing 2 rects in onDraw right?

Answer (score 0):

For me this logic is working fine

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if(columnIndex < rectangles.size()) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= columnIndex; ++i) {
                canvas.drawRect(rectangles.get(i), paint);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest heck is to keep the canvas object as class level variable and always draw on this canvas object and in super.onDraw() pass on this canvas, it will always keep your previous rectangles drawn

Comment: Do you mean a static variable ? I did it, but nothing changed

Comment: private Canvas mCanvas; @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {if(mCanvas == null)mCanvas=canvas;
        
            for (int i = 0; i <= columnIndex; ++i) {
                mCanvas.drawRect(rectangles.get(i), paint);
            }
        super.onDraw(mCanvas);
    }